# How do I reference parent table in a multi table join?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a representation of my table(s).  `Table a` is sort of a parent (id being the primary key). `b and c` have varying number of rows (its `pid` is a reference to parent).

```
mysql> select * from a;
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
| 1    | Ruby |
+------+------+

mysql> select * from b;
+------+------+
| pid  | name |
+------+------+
| 1    | Java |
| 1    | C++  |
+------+------+

mysql> select * from c;
+------+------+-------+
| id   | pid  | name  |
+------+------+-------+
| 100  | 1    | Ember |
+------+------+-------+
```

I am trying to achieve either of the below:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| id   | name | pid  | name | id   | pid  | name  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 1    | Ruby | 1    | Java | 100  | 1    | Ember |
| 1    | Ruby | 1    | C++  | NULL | NULL | NULL  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

OR

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| id   | name | pid  | name | id   | pid  | name  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 1    | Ruby | 1    | Java | 100  | 1    | Ember |
| NULL | NULL | 1    | C++  | NULL | NULL | NULL  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

Left Outer join doesn't quite produce what I wanted (because the 2nd join is done on the result of the first join thus producing 2 rows);

```
mysql> select *
    ->   from A
    ->   left outer join B ON a.id = b.pid
    ->   left outer join C ON a.id = c.pid;
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| id   | name | pid  | name | id   | pid  | name  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| 1    | Ruby | 1    | Java | 100  | 1    | Ember |
| 1    | Ruby | 1    | C++  | 100  | 1    | Ember |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

Comment: If everything has an id of 1 then why wouldn't Ember be related to C++/Ruby?

Comment: I have amended the value of `id` in table c for clarity.

Comment: @Bala The change of ID in the C table doesn't change anything. You need to have a foreign key from C to B to be able to achieve what you want (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

The results you get are expected. You should have a different id for C++ and that would lead to the results you want.

You need to add and ID column in the `B` table that you would use in the `C` table (as a foreign key) so that you can filter the results.

Fixing this database design issue will help you solve this problem as your current design is flawed.

The resulting query should look like :

```
SELECT *
FROM A
   LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.id = B.pid
   LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON A.id = B.pid AND C.newForeignKeyId=B.newId;
```

Also, I would recommend using `IDENTITY` id columns that increment automatically so that you don't run into integrity problems.

Comment: I am sure the look of tables(s) design appear to be flawed. But these tables are temporary tables and the contents are read from multiple messages on Message Queues.