# How to create table as select from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql

How do I go about creating a table from multiple tables having variable columns (union cannot be used)?

```
mysql> select * from a;
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
| 1    | Ruby |
+------+------+

mysql> select * from b;
+------+------+
| pid  | name |
+------+------+
| 1    | Java |
| 1    | C++  |
+------+------+
```

What I want...

```
+------+------+------+------+
| id   | name | pid  | bname|
+------+------+------+------+
| 1    | Ruby |      |      |
|      |      | 1    | C++  |
|      |      | 1    | Java |
+------+------+------+------+
```

What I have tried.

```
mysql> create table t as select * from a; # worked fine
mysql> alter table t as select pid, name as bname from b; #didn't work
```

Comment: Why can't you use `union`?

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: @Strawberry: I wanted it to achieve my earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531279/how-do-i-reference-parent-table-in-a-multi-table-join

Comment: But if you're after something like this, why bother with the concept of relational data at all?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in this rather arcane way:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a left join
     b
     on 1 = 0
union all
select a.*, b.*
from b left join
     a
     on 1 = 0;
```

This is one way, in MySQL of implementing:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a full outer join
     b
     on 1 = 0;
```

But, it requires a `union`.  You could do it in two steps if you want to avoid the `union`:

```
create table ab as
    select a.*, b.*
    from a left join
         b
         on 1 = 0;

insert into ab
    select a.*, b.*
    from b left join
         a
         on 1 = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem to use `union`, you just need to select `null`s as the columns that aren't in the table:

```
CREATE TABLE t AS
SELECT id, name, null AS pid, null AS bname
FROM   a
UNION ALL
SELECT null, null, pid, bname
FROM   b
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the new table, containing all four columns. Then

```
INSERT INTO t (id, name) SELECT * FROM a;
INSERT INTO t (pid, bname) SELECT * FROM b;
```

The first line will put everything from `a` in there, and leave the other two fields as `NULL`; the second will do the corresponding thing from `b`. You could do the whole thing in one `CREATE`/`UNION` statement, but if this is a one-off operation, it's probably easier to understand what you're doing if you do it in stages like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this this as an example.
Create a new table (name, date of birth) by joining two tables (student id, name) and (student id, date of birth).

Create first table:

```
create table stu1(student_id char(5) primary key,name varchar(45))ENGINE=innodb;
```

Create second table:

```
create table stu2(student_id char(5) primary key,dob date)ENGINE=innodb;
```

Create third table (by joining two tables):

```
create table stu3 AS(select stu1.name,stu2.dob from stu1,stu2  
                                      where stu1.student_id=stu2.student_id);
```